# Using express-flash with Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, express

I am following a tutorial that uses ejs5. That tutorial wants me to use express-flash, and organize my `routes/users` page like so.

```
router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('accounts/signup', {
        errors: req.flash('errors')
    });
});
```

The subsequent es5 goes something like so:

```
<% if (errors.length > 0) { %>
<%= errors %>
<% } %>
```

For myself, I am instead using Express-Handlebars. Now, I know that my `app.js` file has everything it needs, since my routing to `/signup` works like so:

```
router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('accounts/signup');     
 });
```

However, if I reformat my router code as shown in the first example, I get a 404 error on my `signup` route. I do not understand why that is. To demonstrate, this is what I have, identical to the first example.

```
//render the signup//
router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('accounts/signup', {
        errors: req.flash('errors')
    });
});
```

To be sure, my main app.js file contains the following:

```
var flash = require('express-flash');
app.use(flash());
```

In addition to this, I am also unsure how to replicate the ejs script using Handlebars. Would doing something like this work?

```
{{#if errors.length > 0}}
     {{errors}}
{{/if}}
```

I am unable to test this as I first need to get my sign up route showing.

Comment: Are you using `handlebars` or `express-handlebars`?

Comment: Sorry. express-handlebars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a flash helper and use that in the main template.

```
// set context for the req, res
app.use(require('./../web/helpers/view').setContext);

exphbs.create({
    extname      :'hbs',
    layoutsDir   : '/path/',
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    helpers      : require('/path/to/view').helpers, // this is where you can register a helper.
    partialsDir  : [
        '/path/'
    ]
});
```

In `view.js`, write a method to build html out of the flash message.

```
'use strict';

const _ = require('lodash');

let  _req, _res;

// build html for flash messages. 
function renderFlashMsg() {
    let flash = _req.flash(),
        out   = '',
        types = ['success', 'error', 'info'];

    _.each(types, (type) => {
        if (flash[type]) {
            out += '<div class="flash-msgs '+ type +'">';
            out += '<h2><span>' + type + '</span></h2>';
            out += '<ul>';

            _.each(flash[type], (msg) => {
                out += `<li>${msg}</li>`;
            }) ;

            out += '</ul></div>';
        }
    });

    return out;
}

module.exports = {
    'setContext': (req, res, next) => {
        _req = req;
        _res = res;
        next();
    },
    'helpers': {
        renderFlashMsg
    }
};
```

Now you have can just use `renderFlashMsg` in your `main` layout file.

Put `{{{renderFlashMsg}}}` where you want the flash messages to be placed in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setup view engine for handlebars template?

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({/* config */}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Or change extension of file to .handlebars